# .Net Core Web API, create a routing logic to different controllers with same route prefix based on a value

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have to create a routing logic for a .Net Core 3.0 Web API project that routes to different controllers with same route prefix given a value.

Example:
I have controllers based on states.

```
StateUsersCOController
StateUsersCAController
StateUsersWAController
```

and such.

They all implement the same method such as:

```
GetUsers();
```

What I want to achieve is my request routed to a related controller based on state information such as:

```
api/StateUsers/CA
```

or

```
api/StateUsers?state=CA
```

or

```
api/StateUsers and Request Header has the state Information such as State:CA
```

What I can come up is creating a controller called StateUsers, capture the state value in one of the provided ways mentioned above and redirect the request to related controller, but I want to avoid redirection and achieve this is routing level. Can you guys please provide a better way to do this.

Comment: will you pass multiple parameters?

Comment: no only single state parameter

Comment: You can try something similar to [this](https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/)

Comment: @Eldar tried the solution given in link, although it seems promising, I am using APIController attribute and it requires Route attribute which overrides conventional routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute routing with fixed route templates should be able to uniquely differentiate the controllers

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/StateUsers/CO")]
public class StateUsersCOController : Controller {
    //GET api/StateUsers/CO
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUsers() {
        //...
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/StateUsers/CA")]
public class StateUsersCAController : Controller {
    //GET api/StateUsers/CA
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUsers() {
        //...
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/StateUsers/WA")]
public class StateUsersWAController : Controller {
    //GET api/StateUsers/WA
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUsers() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Note the removal of `GetUsers` from the route to allow for a more simplified RESTFul URL.

If you insist on including `GetUsers` in the URL, then include it in the rout template.

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: Removed the Action method name from the URL, this answer seems like the easiest and most convenient since I have tried something like this https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/ but I am using apicontroller attribute and it requires use of route attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the route for it using route attribute, as far as I understand you don't want to have 3 different controllers in order to avoid code duplication so you may try something like:

```
namespace Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/stateusers")]
    public class StateUsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        public StateUsersController()
        {
        }

        // GET api/stateusers/getusers/{state}
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getusers/{state}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(string state)
        {
            //Implement your logic
        }
        
        //Or
        
        // GET api/stateusers/{state}
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{state}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersByState(string state)
        {
            //Implement your logic
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I would advise you to have a look on the following website [REST Resource Naming Guide](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) where you can check the guidelines for RESTful APIs naming.

Comment: use of different controllers depending on different states is a hard requirement for this task.